# wordpress deletes <sup> on save comment

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, wysiwyg, trumbowyg

I'm trying to implement an WYSIWYG editor to my WP comment section. I experience many difficulties with saving the HTML data in the WordPress database. WP strips many of the HTML tags automatically. I was able to restore the

tags trough the 'preprocess_comment' filter. I added the wpautop() filter to the content. Now the line breaks are appearing. But when I want to use the  tag, WordPress deletes is too.

I use the Trumbowysiwyg js solution to replace the default comment textarea with the wysiwyg editor. When using the editor, the HTML code looks nice. It has all the HTML tags but after saving the comment, these tags are stripped. Can someone tell me how to allow HTML comments to be saved in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress keeps a list of allowed tags which you can use in comments, surely you do not want users to post any html they want. So I suggest you edit the allowedtags so they will not be removed.

```
add_action('comment_post', 'allow_more_tags');

function allow_more_tags() {
   global $allowedtags;
   $allwedtags['sup'] = array('class'=>array());
}
```

Like this you can add any tags you like and even allow certain classs to be added to them.

Comment: Great! This really helps. What would you recommend as 'save' tags?